# Strengthened 'auto' in C++

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator, auto

Once upon a time I realized I want to be able to write code like this without duplicating the code:

```
template<std::size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const vector_type<N>& vector)
{
    if constexpr (passed_by_value<typename vector_type<N>::value_type>)
    {
        for (const auto val : vector)
        {
            o << val << ' ';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (const auto& val : vector)
        {
            o << val << ' ';
        }
    }

    return o;
}
```

The duplicated code in the example is `o << val << ' '` (or maybe the whole loop).

Of course, I know that to avoid the code duplication we could introduce a function that does contains the code. However that is not really the solution I want. I want it to be simple and concise.

The reason I use `if constexpr` in the example is that I want my template function to be able to handle both containers of value types and containers of ref-types. So in one block I do `const auto` whereas in other one - `const auto&`.

It would be wonderful if we could implement a type `super_type` that would behave like this:

```
int passed_by_value = 100;
std::string passed_by_ref = "abcdefghijklmnop";
super_auto value = passed_by_value; // works like auto
super_auto value = passed_by_ref; // works like auto&
const super_auto value = passed_by_value; // works like const auto
const super_auto value = passed_by_ref; // works like const auto&
```

Thus we could write the following code that would work both with value- and ref-types:

```
for (const super_auto val : vector)
{
    o << val << ' ';
}
```

That looks just similar to forwarding ref, however it is not always ref, so forwarding refs do not seem to help us with it.

So the question is how can we implement the logic I've described? Am I mistaken anywhere? Or are there any solutions to this in std lib?

Comment: I don't get why you need `if`, the `else` block works well and is optimal in the both cases.

Comment: `for (const auto& val : vector)` is very likely the optimal approach for all types.

Comment: _The reason I use if constexpr in the example is that I want my template function to be able to handle both containers of value types and containers of ref-types_ - There are no C++ containers that contain references, at least no standard ones.

Comment: @chrysante you didn't catch me right. Under 'ref-types' I understand the types that are more optimal to pass by reference than by value. But that's my bad, I'm about to set my question right.

Comment: @DrewDormann not really. When you do `const auto&` you always add another level of dereference. For some types that's admissible. However, it is rather not optimal to do so with int, for example. Copy 4 bytes (usually) is easier then create an 8 byte (usually) reference.

Comment: [Premuture optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) **Copy 4 bytes (usually) is easier then create an 8 byte (usually) reference** - 1. this is not true. 2. An iterator of std::vector returns a reference.

Comment: @CapyMaths That is an incorrect assumption.  The "another level of dereference"  is an abstraction within the language.  It does not force the compiled machine code to be less efficient.   [See for yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/c5WEGrb4r) - the generated assembly is **the same** for both versions of the loop you have written.  There is no benefit gained from the complexity you are attempting.

Comment: @CapyMaths this rule that you should pass small things by value only really applies when we talk about passing arguments to functions. There is a reason that the standard does not specify what references are, in particular it does not say that references are pointers. The reason is that, locally, the compiler often does not need additional pointer variables to model references. Both versions of your code compile to the same machine code as you can see in the other comment. -- And also when passing things to functions the performance difference is most often negligible.

Comment: Oh, thank you for that. Now I seem to understand all that more correctly. Thank you all for clarifications and explanations.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) can produce a type based on a compile time bool.

```
template<std::size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const vector_type<N>& vector)
{
    using value_type = typename vector_type<N>::value_type;

    using super_auto = std::conditional_t<
            passed_by_value<value_type>, 
            value_type, 
            value_type& >;
            
    for (const super_auto val : vector)
    {
        o << val << ' ';
    }

    return o;
}
```

That said, **it is unlikely that this complexity is benefiting you in any way.**

The code below clearly and efficiently does the same work.

```
template<std::size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const vector_type<N>& vector)
{
    for (const auto& val : vector)
    {
        o << val << ' ';
    }

    return o;
}
```

Comment: Since you made an alias, `passed_by_value<typename vector_type<N>::value_type>` could be simplified to `passed_by_value<value_type>` - and perhaps `using value_type = std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(vector))>::value_type;` would make it a bit more generic.

Comment: @TedLyngmo good catch!  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. That looks good, but indeed I had wanted something that would work a little more implicitly. Using `std::conditional` requires specifying the types. However, for me, `auto` is more about omitting the type specification by its implicit deduction. So I would be satisfied only if you provided the way of achieving the described deduction without any additional local typedefs or something. Probably `super_auto` might be some struct or class that I would include and use with no knowledge of the type manipulations under its hood.

Comment: @CapyMaths If you use `using value_type = std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(vector))>::value_type` then `value_type` will be deduced  even  for plain C arrays of different types. Since you want to use different types depending on your type trait, I don't think you'll get it simpler than by using `std::conditional` as Drew showed in this answer.